# Shortening Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there is probably a way of shortening this function with the new ES6 trying my best to work it out, could anyone shorten this so it still functions as it should? That way maybe I can see what I am doing wrong and why this isn't working....

Thank you!

```
userSchema.methods.isAdmin = function () {
    let found = false
    this.flags.forEach(
        ({type, flag}) => {
            if (type == "UF" && flag == "ISADMIN") {
                found = true
            }
        })
    return found
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the ES5 `some` array method, nothing ES6-specific. Although with a simple ES6 `for … of` loop you could just write an early `return true` and wouldn't need that `found` variable. I recommend avoiding `forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return early.

```
userSchema.methods.isAdmin = function() {
    return this.flags.some(({ type, flag }) => type === "UF" && flag === "ISADMIN");
};
```

Comment: Ah, i was looking at this... so this basically returns true as soon as it finds a match?

Comment: right. the iteration stops at the first returning of a truthy value.